# Joint two lists in the SharePoint blog site using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest

I have two SharePoint lists. 1) Posts and 2) Categories

The Posts list has a lookup field called `Category` into the Categories list.

I am trying to use the `$expand` option to join the two lists but I'm unsuccessful.

I'm trying to follow the example used in this [site](http://www.threewill.com/using-the-expand-odata-query-option-in-sharepoint-2013/) but I'm confused.

Any ideas?

I've tried the following and many other combinations but I get errors

```
http://[...]/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Posts')/Items?$select=Title,PostsCategoryId/Id&$expand=PostsCategoryId
```

Comment: Have you searched for an answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26479319/sharepoint-2013-rest-how-to-select-a-look-up-field-and-also-filter-based-on-look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using the blog site definition, the Posts list has the category field defined as `PostCategory`

Try:

```
blog/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Posts')/Items?$select=Title,PostCategory/Title&$expand=PostCategory
```

Make sure you're using the sub-site `_api` endpoint if you're not at your site root

Comment: That did not work.  Maybe a look at the list can help shed a little light.   http://understandsp.com/blog/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx

Comment: I get an error. Category does not even show up in the xml.  It shows up as PostCategoryId.  See    http://understandsp.com/blog/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/SitePages/Home.aspx

Comment: I get a page can not be found.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29573/discussion-between-justme-and-john-m).

Comment: The following worked.  You were missing a /Title on the end ?$select=Title,PostCategory/Title&$expand=PostCategory/Title